# Web api routes with multiple actions with different parameters

Tags: asp.net

In a ASP.NET Web api project I have a VacationController where I want to use these action methods.
How can I construct the routes to achieve this?

```
    public Enumerable<Vacation> GetVacation()
    {
        // Get all vactions

        return vacations;
    }

    public Vacation GetVacation(int id)
    {
        // Get one vaction

        return vacation;
    }

    public Enumerable<Vacation> ByThemeID(int themeID)
    {
        // Get all vactions by ThemeID

        return vacations;
    }
```

I would like the URL's to look like this

```
/api/vacation             // All vacations
/api/vacation/5           // One vacation
/api/vacation/ByThemeID/5 // All vacations from one theme
```

**Edit 30-10-2013**

I have tried Pasit R routes but I can't getting to work. I verily tried every combination I could think of.

This is what I have know. As you can see I have added a extra parameter at the bein of the route. I realized that I needed that in order to seperate the Vacations sold onder different labels.

Here are the routes I use. and the work OK for these URL's

```
/api/vacation             // All vacations
/api/vacation/5           // One vacation
/api/vacation/ByThemeID/5 // All vacations from one theme
```

But it dosn't work for the last URL

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiSimbo",
            routeTemplate: "api/{label}/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And here my Action method in the VacationController

```
// ByThemeID api/{label}/Vacation/ByThemeId/{id}
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Vacation> ByThemeID(string label, int id)
    {
        return this.repository.Get(label);
    }

    // GET api/{label}/Vacation
    public IEnumerable<Vacation> GetVacation(string label)
    {
        return repository.Get(label);
    }

    // GET api/{label}/Vacation/{id}
    public Vacation GetVacation(string label, int id)
    {
        Vacation vacation;
        if (!repository.TryGet(label, id, out vacation))
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        return vacation;
    }
```

Can some one give my a push in the right direction ;-)

Thanks in advance

Anders Pedersen

Comment: What do you want the routes to look like? There are approximately an infinite number of different ways that routes could be set up to access these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the class is name **VacationController**, then a default routes for these methods would look something like:

```
 /api/Vacation/GetVacation
 /api/Vacation/GetVacation?id=1
 /api/Vacation/ByThemeID?id=1
```

**This is all assuming that the routing has note been updated.**

Answer (score 0):

add defaults action = "GetVacation" and make id as optional

the ApiController base class could handle overload `GetVacation()` and `GetVacation(int id)` selection automatically.

to register WebApiConfig

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{*param}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get", param = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Vacation",
            routeTemplate: "api/vacation/{action}/{*id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Vacation", action = "GetVacation", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Pasit. But what dos the Astrix means {*param} and {*id}?

Comment: the last parameter with * means to map all remaining segments eg. `/api/vacation/theme/dark/light` map to `param = "dark/light"`
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX for complete details

Comment: Thanks Pasit R. Will test in my app tomorrow, I'm now on the road.